# Can one copy a relpath in one command?

Tags: command-line, files, directory, cp

I find myself doing this often enough that I wonder if there's a standard Unix way to do it:

```
% mkdir -p /TARGETDIR/relative/path/to
% cp ./relative/path/to/somefile /TARGETDIR/relative/path/to
```

In other words, I don't want to just copy `somefile` to `/TARGETDIR`, but actually I want to copy its entire *relative path*.

Is there a simpler way to do this than the two-liner above?

Comment: you could use `rsync` to "mirror" one directory/filesystem to the other (including structure)

Comment: @h3rrmiller How do you propose to do that (in a way that isn't `cp -R relative /TARGETDIR`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU coreutils (non-embedded Linux, Cygwin):

```
cp -p --parents path/to/somefile /TARGETDIR
```

With the POSIX tool [`pax`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/pax.html) (which many default installations of Linux unfortunately lack):

```
pax -rw -pp relative/path/to/somefile /TARGETDIR
```

With its traditional counterpart [`cpio`](http://man.cat-v.org/unix_8th/1/cpio):

```
find relative/path/to/somefile | cpio -p -dm /TARGETDIR
```

(This last command assumes that file names don't contain newlines; if the file names may be chosen by an attacker, use some other method, or use `find … -print0 | cpio -0 …` if available.)

Alternatively, you could make it a shell script or function.

```
cp_relpath () {
  mkdir -p -- "$2/$(dirname -- "$1")"
  cp -Rp -- "$1" "$2/$(dirname -- "$1")"
}
```

Comment: I'd say that `cp`'s `-p` is irrelevant to the matter of the question (as well as writing scripts/programs is obviously redundant — actually I'm tempting to see another "answer" with version in Fortran, Cobol and Haskel, may be).

Comment: @poige It isn't, but usually the option is desirable, so I include it by default.

Comment: "Usually" != "really needed in question"

Comment: So, to conclude — the only difference between our answers really worth mentioning was `pax` "which many default installations of Linux unfortunately lack". Entropy thanks you, чо.

Comment: @poige Besides `cp --parents`, I wanted to mention pax and cpio for the non-Linux audience, and show how to do it with a function.

Comment: That's gr8 indeed, I agree.

Comment: BTW, isn't it best practice to always use `-print0` with `find` and, hence, `-0` with `cpio`. I bet you'd better put those instead of that irrelevant `-p`.

Comment: @poige If you don't have pax and can't easily install it, you must be on some old or very limited system that may not have `-print0`, but that probably has no dangerous file names either (typically it's some long-running server or an embedded device, and it's a controlled environment either way).

Comment: If I don't have `pax` that's because I don't need it, but what I do have is both GNU's `cp` and understanding that `find` *should* be used with `-print0` and answers *should* be given w/o extraneous, irrelevant entities "just because usually they're desirable".

Comment: @poige Please do edit mistaken or incomplete answers, but do not add irrelevant digressions (that is a privilege of the author) and do not change the tone of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

`man cp` reveals `--parents`. So simple, yeah.

```
$ mkdir /tmp/myetc && cp --parents init.d/cron /tmp/myetc && find /tmp/myetc/
/tmp/myetc/
/tmp/myetc/init.d
/tmp/myetc/init.d/cron
```

Comment: Note that `--parents` is a GNUism (it is _only_ a long version flag).